# Looking for a secure way to share files over the internet

Tags: security, file-permissions, onedrive, file-sharing

Currently i am working on a project and the requirement is to share the financial files and documents securely over the internet. Idea is to give only relevant person access of the file and even he should not be allowed to download the file. Authorized person should be working on the file on a secure server and can have only read and write access, he shouldn't be allowed to download the file.
What we are looking for is a solution

- Where remote team can work on a file (excel, word) on a secure server but they are not allowed to download that
- Share files among groups and individuals and no one else have access of these files other than authorized person
- All the changes can be recored (nice to have feature)

Sharefile looks promising, OneDrive is confusing.

Comment: There is no functional difference between a read and a download.

Comment: We need a user to work on the file on a cloud/server .. but he shouldnt be allowed to download the file.

Comment: On sharefile you can restrict him to view, but its not possible for a user to work on the file..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SMB protocol (share the folder you want to manage).
First of all if your machines are supporting SMBv3, you can use an encryption network transfer, second you can use the Security Descriptors (and ACL for each user to determine the security privilege - right click on the File/Folder -> security tab and so on in windows OS)

Comment: Thanks, but i want to keep it platform independent.

Comment: If you search you will see the using SMB make your platform independed. They are all support SMB, maybe Android will not.